# Why Python Pandas append to DataFrame like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add l in column 'A' but it creates a new column and adds l to the last one. Why is it happening? And how can I make what I want?

```
import pandas as pd

l=[1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['A'])
df = df.append(l, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append(l, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
     A    0
0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  1.0
4  NaN  2.0
5  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: append is for adding *rows* to a DataFrame, not columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**
Is this what you want to do:

```
In[6]:df=df.A.append(pd.Series(l)).reset_index().drop('index',1).rename(columns={0:'A'})

In[7]:df
Out[7]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Then you can add any list of different length.
Suppose:

```
a=[9,8,7,6,5]

In[11]:df=df.A.append(pd.Series(a)).reset_index().drop('index',1).rename(columns={0:'A'})

In[12]:df
Out[12]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  9
4  8
5  7
6  6
7  5
```

**Previously**
are you looking for this :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['A'])

df
Out[5]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: No. I have to constantly (in a loop) add new elements to the column A, and list 'l' always (with any new iteration of a loop) has different elements and different length.

Comment: @Tragen is this what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass a dictionary in the dataframe constructor, that if I understand your question correctly.

```
l = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': l})
df
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Comment: No. I have to constantly (in a loop) add new elements to the column A, and list 'l' always (with any new iteration of a loop) has different elements and different length.